# Game Theory Projects for Undergrads

Tags: education, game-theory

I am looking for some project ideas for beginning math students in the topic of game theory. I am not very knowledgeable in the topic so it would be great if I could get an good introductory source to learn the material with these students and then a project idea as a semester end-goal. It would be fun if it was a project that could set two students strategies against one another but not necessary.

Comment: I am not looking for an open problem or research project, just an introduction to the topic for math beginners.

Comment: MIT OpenCourseWare, subject Game Theory (undergraduate) .

Comment: Maybe revisit http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/1998-99/game-theory/axelrod.html ?